# App crashes with very low memory usage iphone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory, crash, ios-simulator

I have read lot of posts regarding Low memory warning crash, But I was unable to solve the problem of crash in my app. The Allocation of instruments shows Live bytes ranging from 2-7MB. It never spikes beyond 7 or 7.5MB but still app crashes.

I read some links which tells that Allocations and Activity monitor shows different values of memory usage. As specified earlier, Allocations will show max of 7-7.5MB but Activity monitor shows about 75MB usage when app is launched and as I use the program, it starts increasing and decreasing. It will go up to 110-120MB and then reduce to 75-80MB.

Some more links says to look at Dirty size and resident size in VM Tracker. When I check in VM Tracker, the Dirty size will start from 30MB and starts to increase as I use the app. It goes beyond 400MB. I am using about 150 images in which about 70-80 are of 1024x1024 size, about 35 are in 110x110 and rest are of 3000x4000 sized image. All of these images were originally in png format and I have programatically converted to JPG+ALPHA and added as asset to a application. Whenever corresponding image has to be loaded, I divide the JPG+ALPHA image into 16 parts and finally join them to get original image. I am doing this because when I tried to load image of resolution 3000x4000, memory was spiking till 40-45MB in Allocations, so used this method. This method makes sure that the memory will never be exceeded more than 10MB.

All of these records and statistics are measured using Simulator.

Application never crashes on Simulator but it crashes on real device. I am using iPad2 for testing.

Please help me to solve this problem. I am stuck from past 2 days and completely frustrated by seeing app crash.

Comment: Search for `heapshots`, it's a functionality of the Allocations tool. You can track what memory got alloc'd and dealloc'd at specific time intervals. Also, fyi, some image handling methods use cacheing, like `imageNamed`. You could also try with `NSAutoreleasePool`, because there are so many images in memory at the same time.

Comment: what does the crash log say...?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Templar. I have used NSAutoreleasePool everywhere and I am using initWithContentsOfTheFile to load the contents of image. Will try with heapshots and post the result here.

Comment: and if it is crashing due to low Memory warning then you are surely don't setting nil some of your objects in viewDidUnload

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava Crash log says "jettisoned". As I have read in some posts, jettisoned means crash because of Low memory warning. Am I right?

Comment: Probably yes, but you should implement `didReceiveMemoryWarning` in the app delegate or in this view to see when or what causes this. Probably you can set a breakpoint on this method so it will stop there. Btw, did you do some "leak" tests with Instruments ? If not, I highly recommend it !

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava I have released all the objects which I have used and they have been assigned to nil in viewDidUnload.

Comment: @Templar I have implemented didReceiveMemoryWarning method in the view. I have done leak test and there are no memory leaks.

Comment: @SRIKANTH KV did you got the solution?

Comment: The problem you are running into is that iOS kills your app because you are allocating too much memory. Images that are 3000x4000 would consume 48 megs of memory for each one. That is too large. You need to rethink your basic approach, this one will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Is this code correct?

```
    UIImageView* framebadgeOrAccessoryImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:sizeOfFrameOrAccessoriesView];
    [framebadgeOrAccessoryImage setCenter:imageArea.center];
    [framebadgeOrAccessoryImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [framebadgeOrAccessoryImage setImage:badgeOrAccessoryImage];
    [framebadgeOrAccessoryImage setTag:iObjectTag];
    [framebadgeOrAccessoryImage setObservationInfo:@"BadgeAccessories"];
    [framebadgeOrAccessoryImage setExclusiveTouch:YES];

    iObjectTag++;

    [framebadgeOrAccessoryImage setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    [framebadgeOrAccessoryImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [framebadgeOrAccessoryImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [imageArea addSubview:framebadgeOrAccessoryImage];

selectedItem = framebadgeOrAccessoryImage;

    [framebadgeOrAccessoryImage release];
```

I am using "framebadgeOrAccessoryImage" in my other methods using the tag which I have set. Do I have to just release "framebadgeOrAccessoryImage" as I have done in the last line of the code or assign it to nil after releasing it?

"framebadgeOrAccessoryImage" is used here with the name "selectedItem".

```
- (void)panRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{   
    if(selectedItem.image && [gestureRecognizer isEnabled])
    {
        UIImageView *piece = selectedItem;

        if ((([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)) && [((NSString*) [piece observationInfo]) isEqualToString:@"BadgeAccessories"])
        {
            CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:[piece superview]];
            [piece setCenter:CGPointMake([piece center].x + translation.x, [piece center].y + translation.y)];
            [gestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[piece superview]];

        }

        if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ||[gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)
        {   
            if(CGRectContainsPoint([[self view]viewWithTag:RECYCLEBIN_TAG].frame, [gestureRecognizer locationInView:imageArea]))
            {
                NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
                [objectsAdded removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",selectedItem.tag]];
                [pool release];
                [UIView beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];
                [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
                [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
                [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(propDeleted:finished:context:)];
                [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

                [selectedItem setFrame:CGRectMake(selectedItem.frame.origin.x, selectedItem.frame.origin.y, 5, 5)];
                selectedItem.center = [[[self view]viewWithTag:RECYCLEBIN_TAG]center];
                [UIView commitAnimations];
            }
            else
            {
                [self applyEffectOnTouch:0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the other code that uses `framebadgeOrAccessoryImage`.  That sounds like a likely place for the problem.  But, please, don't put your code here.  This area is for answers.  Use the **Edit** link below the question, and put the code into your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The images you're trying to load are very large. Perhaps you should consider using a CATiledLayer to display the images. You can find the apple class definition [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Also consider the difference between making your image easier to render versus reducing the memory usage of your pictures. If you split your images into smaller pieces you will be reducing individual draw loads but you will still run into memory issues if each of those images is loaded into memory.

The tiled layer displays very large images while keeping memory usage down by attempting to load visible tiles only.

Also, your simulator does not have the memory limits of the actual device. You should perform all stress tests on the actual device.

EDIT: You should also refrain from using UIImage imageNamed as it caches the image and can make your memory problems even worse. Use imageWithContentsOfFile instead.

Comment: Thanks. I am using "imageWithContentsOfFile" method. Since I have JPG+ALPHA separated image in my bundle, I need to convert those images into png file just before showing it on the screen. I cannot use CATiledLayer because I have to previously convert the JPG+ALPHA to png. As I have stated earlier in the post, the Allocations records the memory to the max of 7-7.5MB but the Dirty size is reaching about 400MB in VM Tracker. How can I reduce the Dirty size or how can I claim that part of memory?